# Convert Dictionary.keyscollection to array of strings

Tags: c#, collections

I have a `Dictionary<string, List<Order>>` and I want to have the list of keys in an array. But when I choose

```
string[] keys = dictionary.Keys;
```

This doesn't compile.

How do I convert `KeysCollection` to an array of Strings?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Assuming you're using .NET 3.5 or later (`using System.Linq;`):

```
string[] keys = dictionary.Keys.ToArray();
```

Otherwise, you will have to use the CopyTo method, or use a loop :

```
string[] keys = new string[dictionary.Keys.Count];
dictionary.Keys.CopyTo(keys, 0);
```

Comment: Using C++/CLI and .net 3.5 I get this when I try: `error C2039: 'ToArray' : is not a member of 'System::Collections::Generic::Dictionary<TKey,TValue>::KeyCollection'`

Comment: @JonCage, `ToArray` is an extension method defined in `System.Linq.Enumerable`; as far as I know, C++/CLI doesn't support extension method, so you have to call it as a normal static method: `System::Linq::Enumerable::ToArray(dictionary.Keys)`

Comment: I know this is super old but for those of us developing for SharePoint, thank you for including the older framework solution.

Comment: Thanks Thomas Levesque. I was able to do use your hint to solve my problem: string[] objSessionKeys = System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray<string>((IEnumerable<string>)session.Keys); --it compiles - I hope it works. I hadn't known ToArray was an extension method before.

Answer (score 4):

Use this if your keys isn't of type string. It requires LINQ.

```
string[] keys = dictionary.Keys.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Comment: This returns an `IEnumerable<string>`, not a `string[]`

Comment: Also, it's clear from the OP that the keys are of type `string` (though originally there was a formatting problem that prevented it from showing).

Comment: As my answer says, use it if your key isn't of type string and you still want a string...

Answer (score 4):

With `dictionary.Keys.CopyTo (keys, 0);`

If you don't need the array (which you usually don't need) you can just iterate over the Keys.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't have VS nearby to check this, but I think something like this might work:

```
var keysCol = dictionary.Keys;
var keysList = new List<???>(keysCol);
string[] keys = keysList.ToArray();
```

where ??? is your key type.

Comment: `new List<T>(my.dict.Keys)` worked for my case

Answer (score 1):

Or perhaps a handy generic extension...

```
    public static T2[] ToValueArray<T1, T2>(this Dictionary<T1, T2> value)
    {
        var values = new T2[value.Values.Count];
        value.Values.CopyTo(values, 0);

        return values;
    }
```