# Converting dictionary keys to array in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I convert a dictionary keys' to array in Unity 4.3? (**other than manually, of course**)

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1621357/207655) doesn't seem to work, and I'm puzzled about why.

Code:

```
private Dictionary<int,Client> uid2Client;
public static int[] uidList
{
    get
    {
        return instance.uid2Client.Keys.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Error:

> Assets/sources/ClientServer.cs(144,57): error CS1061: Type
>   `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int,Client>.KeyCollection' does
>   not contain a definition for `ToArray' and no extension method
>   `ToArray' of type
>   `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int,Client>.KeyCollection'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `ToArray()` method is not a standard part of the KeyCollection class. It's an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) added by [Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx).

Add `Using System.Linq;` to the beginning of your class file.

Comment: Actually, they cover this in the [first comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621351/convert-dictionary-keyscollection-to-array-of-strings/1621357#comment23394266_1621357) on the accepted solution to the question you link...

Comment: Didn't notice the comment. They say they are ephemeral and should be incorporated into the posts, don't they? ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try manually extracting the keys into an array:

```
int[] getKeys()
{
    List<int> keys = new List<int>();
    var keycollection = uid2Client.Keys;
    foreach(var key in keycollection)
    {
        keys.Add(key);
    }
    int[] keyArray = keys.ToArray();
    return keyArray;
}
```

Comment: Sure I can do it manually, the whole point of this question is to understand if there is an automatic, possibly one-line, way. Also, to understand why that other method doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

```
int[] KeysToArray(){

    int[] array = new List<int>(dictionary.keys).ToArray();

    return array;

}
```

Comment: Why would you want to create a list before converting it to an array? That's just double the work and memory consumption.